# meaning of 'a mark in one's favor'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

This is from the podcast [Stuff You Should Know](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-stuff-you-should-know-26940277/episode/whats-nato-all-about-94894577/):

> But in the early 2000s, America squandered a lot of its credibility, a
> lot of its legitimacy in adventurism like invading Iraq, unprovoked,
> illegally, which, by the way, NATO had nothing to do with because
> the rest of the NATO nations or most of the other NATO nations were
> like “this is not right, we are not going anywhere near it", which is **a**
> **mark in NATO’s favor** if you ask me, that they saw like “this is not,
> this is not just wars, this is an invasion.”

I wonder what 'a mark in one's favor' means in this context.

Comment: Have you ever done a test, and got a good mark (one in your favor or favour?), or a mark not in your favour?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So you mean the speaker is saying that, in his opinion, it was a good job NATO didn't engage in the U.S. invasion of Iraq. Right?

Comment: yes. In the speaker's opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what @MichaelHavey has mentioned, in the speaker's opinion, it was a wise decision that NATO did not engage or interfere with the US invasion or Iraq.

This can also be seen through "we are not going anywhere near it", where "it" refers to the invasion.